# Remedy a negative question

Tags: support, feature-request

I asked what has been received by a user as a 'bad' question two years ago:  [Splitting a single list into three in order using Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056889/prolog-splitting-list-into-3-lists-in-order).
I have learned much since then.  However being my only negative question, it has been somewhat of a thorn in my side.  It also seems to be preventing me from getting a badge requiring a positive question record.  I cannot delete it since it has an answer, but I cannot think of any way to fix it.

Although not the best, I didn't think it is was such a terrible question it deserved a downvote; I didn't ask for the answer, I asked for pointers.  It's also such an old (and niche) question I cannot imagine I would ever get a single upvote on it.

Is there any way I can remedy this?  If not, it would be nice if there were a feature to do so.  Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to rally people to downvote/close-vote it, we could probably get it deleted. But I don't think it's really a big deal; probably nobody will ever see it if they're looking at your profile.

Comment: You want the curious badge? I doubt that question is stopping a positive question record...

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks for being reassuring.  As much as I would like to wipe it out of memory, I agree it's unfair to delete it for the person who was nice enough to answer.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Actually when someone was nice and upvoted it to 0, I got the badge.

Comment: Even boring/trivial question can be made useful to future readers. You already got an attempt, a goal, and a bit of description. It's just that your code lacks comments, and a description of why you thought or how it might have worked. You could even (very very cautiously) pave the way for the existing answer; just keep it terse. -- The best questions are those where you don't even have to look at the answers to learn something new. (And Prolog isn't very widely know.)

Comment: @mario You should make that an answer.  You are right, I'm taking the wrong approach to this.  As per your recommendation I have made changes to my question.